# Running arbitrary MongoDB scripts through Node.js driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a combination of complex MongoDB scripts that runs from the command line as follows:

```
$ mongo mydb config.js task.js
```

Since I can't run shell scripts in my server environment and need to schedule the above task, I figured I could simply concatenate the above .js files and then run them from a Node script. Hence I am looking for an equavalent to:

```
db.runMyCustomRawCommands(string commands)
```

How can I do this, or what would be an alternative solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote Christian Kvalheim, original author of the Node.js native MongoDB driver:

that's not possible as the shell is synchronous and have different apis than the node.js driver. you would have to rewrite the scripts to work for node.js.

Comment: where does this quote come from? can you share the link?

Comment: I emailed him directly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `db.runMyCustomRawCommands` is not a raw command. The drivers communicate with the mongod server on a lower level. Commands such as `db.abc` you run in the console are actually simple query messages referencing the `db.$cmd` collection as `db.$cmd.findOne({ abc: 1 })` or similarly.

You thus have to either figure out how to express your mongo shell script as calls to your driver's API or access the server on a lower level.